# JQuery Tabs' surfaces aren't fully clickable

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a set of JQuery's tabs that work fine--the tabs connect to the divs and everything. The only issue is that unless I put the mouse right over the text of the tab, it will not recognize it as the link, just as part of the "li". What's confusing is that pretty much every example I've seen doesn't have anything extra that I could readily see. I'm almost certain there's just one stupid thing that I'm missing, but I have no clue what it is. Or do I need to add something extra to make the entire "li"?

Here's the code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:75%;
    }
    .tabs ul{
        list-style:none;
        padding:0px;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    .tabs li{
        float:left;
        padding:.5em 0em;
        margin:0px .5em 0px 0px;
        width:120px;
        background-color:#ccc;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .tabs li a{
        color:#666;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .tabs li.ui-tabs-selected{
        background-color:#999;
    }
    .tabs li.ui-tabs-selected a{
        color:#000;
    }
    .tabs div{
        clear:both;
        background-color:#f0f0f0;
        margin:0px;
        padding:.5em 1em;
    }
    .ui-tabs-hide{
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabs").tabs();
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1">First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Second Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Third Tab</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1"><p>This is the first tab.</p></div>
    <div id="tab2"><p>This is the second tab.</p></div>
    <div id="tab3"><p>This is the third tab.</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display:block` to your tabs or your links.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `display` property of `a`, by default it's `inline` but you can change it to `inline-block`

```
.tabs li a{
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;  
}
```

And also you may have to adjust the height `width` and `height`.

[**An Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/G4pWn/1/).

Comment: Close--but inline-block causes the same problem. Turns out it needs just regular old "block".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float:left` from your `.tabs li` rule and put the `width:120px;` on `.tabs li a` instead.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tFKFJ/)**